# Glassfish 3.1.1 start fails

Tags: java, glassfish

I'm running glassfish 3.1.1. on my development machine (using Windows XP) for some time now, but this morning it fails to start. Running
`asadmin start-domain domain1`
it reports:

```
Waiting for domain1 to start .....Error starting domain domain1.
The server exited prematurely with exit code 1.
Before it died, it produced the following output:

Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
Completed shutdown of GlassFish runtime
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMa
in.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.postConstruct(GFFileH
andler.java:159)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.inject(AbstractCreatorImpl.
java:131)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.initialize(ConstructorCreato
r.java:91)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.jav
a:82)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.jav
a:67)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingIn
habitant.java:139)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantIm
pl.java:76)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat$5.get(Habitat.java:701)
        at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:358)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.LogManagerService.postConstruct(Log
ManagerService.java:374)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.inject(AbstractCreatorImpl.
java:131)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.initialize(ConstructorCreato
r.java:91)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.jav
a:82)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.jav
a:67)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingIn
habitant.java:139)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantIm
pl.java:76)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.run(AppServerStartup.ja
va:229)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.doStart(AppServerStartu
p.java:145)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.start(AppServerStartup.
java:136)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishImpl.start(GlassFishI
mpl.java:79)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishDecorator.start(Glass
FishDecorator.java:63)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishImpl.start(O
SGiGlassFishImpl.java:69)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(
GlassFishMain.java:117)
        ... 6 more
```

However, the server.log reads:

Jan 16, 2

```
012 10:59:14 AM com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger info
Information: JVM invocation command line:
C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java.exe
-cp
C:/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:MaxPermSize=192m
-XX:NewRatio=2
-Xmx512m
-client
-javaagent:C:/glassfish3/glassfish/lib/monitor/flashlight-agent.jar
-Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\glassfish3\glassfish/modules/endorsed;C:\glassfish3\glassfish/lib/endorsed
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/cacerts.jks
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as
-DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/login.conf
-Dgosh.args=--nointeractive
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1
-Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
-Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=C:\glassfish3\glassfish/modules/autostart/
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=6666
-Djava.security.policy=C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/server.policy
-Dfelix.fileinstall.log.level=2
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1
-Dcom.sun.aas.instanceRoot=C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1
-Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=C:\glassfish3\glassfish
-Djava.ext.dirs=C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.7.0/lib/ext;C:\Programme\Java\jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/ext;C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1/lib/ext
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true
-Dorg.glassfish.additionalOSGiBundlesToStart=org.apache.felix.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,org.apache.felix.gogo.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.command,org.apache.felix.fileinstall
-Djava.library.path=C:/glassfish3/glassfish/lib;C:/Programme/Java/jdk1.7.0/bin;C:/WINDOWS/Sun/Java/bin;C:/WINDOWS/system32;C:/WINDOWS;C:/Programme/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common;C:/oracle/product/10.2.0/client_1/BIN;C:/WINDOWS/system32/wbem;C:/Programme/Microsoft SQL Server/80/Tools/Binn;C:/WINDOWS/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0;Y:/Maven-3.0.3/bin;C:/TP/ant/bin;Y:/Lotto/JOB-4.3.4-win32/JOB-4.3.4-bin/bin;C:/glassfish3/glassfish/bin
com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain
-domainname
domain1
-asadmin-args
--host,,,localhost,,,--port,,,4848,,,--secure=false,,,--terse=false,,,--echo=false,,,--interactive=true,,,start-domain,,,--verbose=false,,,--debug=false,,,--domaindir,,,C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains,,,domain1
-instancename
server
-verbose
false
-debug
false
-asadmin-classpath
C:/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/admin-cli.jar
-asadmin-classname
com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AsadminMain
-upgrade
false
-type
DAS
-domaindir
C:/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1
-read-stdin
true
Jan 16, 2012 10:59:14 AM com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger info
Information: Successfully launched in 31 msec.
```

We updated to JDK7u2 on Friday, but I was able to start the domain afterwards. The log shows it is still using JDK1.7.0. anyway.

Any ideas?

Comment: Some more research revealed that changing logging properties through the admin console is not a good idea: [Warning, touching the logging properties may trash the GF installation](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/warning-touching-logging-properties-may-trash-gf-installation)

Like posted there, I copied the logging.properties from another installation and everything is fine now.

Comment: Faced the same issue on Glassfish 4.1. Make some changes in logging config and it stops starting, hard to believe.

Comment: Hi @TPete. Would you please mind taking a look at my question [**HERE**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33932682/failed-to-start-osgimoduleimpl-bundle-org-glassfish-main-admingui-glassfish). It is closely related to this one. I will really appreciate it: I'm really stuck. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17161  which is a duplicate of GLASSFISH-17037.  GLASSFISH-17037 is in the release notes.

The workaround is to run a CLI command after adjusting/changing the log levels in console.

%asadmin set-log-levels com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler=ALL 
Specify the --target option for a server instance other than the domain administration server (DAS).

This has been fixed in 3.1.2 Release which is scheduled for FCS soon.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, although I would not call it a duplicate: no more logging is not quite the same as not starting at all, is it?

Answer (score 1):

We resolved the issue by replacing the "logging.properties" file taken from domain1/config/default-config floder and placed into domains/domain1/config/

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall the patch and run your Glassfish server. 
Do you install the patch to the same directory? Maybe you have 2 JDK installed? I don't remember, but maybe Glassfish uses it's own JDK and so you have a clash. Anyway, I recommend you to go to JDK 1.7.0 and try again.

Check also windows environment variables as JAVA_HOME and PATH, maybe the problem is there.

You can also try to uninstall JDK completely, and install JDK 1.7.0_02 (patched one).

Comment: As stated above, this is a known issue of the glassfish server and not related to the JDK update.