# Failed to start OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.glassfish-osgi-console-plugin [302]], State = [NEW]

Tags: java, glassfish

```
com.sun.enterprise.module.ResolveError: Failed to start OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.glassfish-osgi-console-plugin [302]], State = [NEW]
```

I get this error after installing **glassfish-osgi-gui**

I've tried this, but to no success (Windows 7):

1. `glassfish3/bin/asadmin set configs.config.server-config.admin-service.property.adminConsoleStartup=NEVER`
2. `glassfish3/bin/asadmin restart-domain`

**UPDATE : THE STACK-TRACE**

```
com.sun.enterprise.module.ResolveError: Failed to start OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.glassfish-osgi-console-plugin [302]], State = [NEW]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl.start(OSGiModuleImpl.java:218)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OsgiPopulatorPostProcessor$1.loadClass(OsgiPopulatorPostProcessor.java:77)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.loadClass(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2058)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:413)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2223)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:105)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServices(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:767)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ClassLoaderHierarchyImpl.createApplicationParentCL(ClassLoaderHierarchyImpl.java:202)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentContextImpl.createClassLoader(DeploymentContextImpl.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentContextImpl.createDeploymentClassLoader(DeploymentContextImpl.java:229)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:365)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:406)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.load(InstallerThread.java:211)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.run(InstallerThread.java:100)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.glassfish.main.admingui.glassfish-osgi-console-plugin [302]: Unable to resolve 302.0: missing requirement [302.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.handler)(version>=2.1.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3974)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2037)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.OSGiModuleImpl.start(OSGiModuleImpl.java:210)
    ... 14 more
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load descriptor SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=org.glassfish.osgi.admingui.OSGIConsoleProvider
    contracts={org.glassfish.osgi.admingui.OSGIConsoleProvider,org.glassfish.api.admingui.ConsoleProvider}
    scope=javax.inject.Singleton
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=CLASS
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=Bundle-SymbolicName={org.glassfish.main.admingui.glassfish-osgi-console-plugin},Bundle-Version={4.1.1}
    rank=0
    loader=OsgiPopulatorPostProcessor.HK2Loader(OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.glassfish-osgi-console-plugin [302]], State = [NEW],2276567)
    proxiable=null
    proxyForSameScope=null
    analysisName=null
    id=1080
    locatorId=0
    identityHashCode=9500941
    reified=false)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.loadClass(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2067)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:413)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2223)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:105)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServices(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:767)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ClassLoaderHierarchyImpl.createApplicationParentCL(ClassLoaderHierarchyImpl.java:202)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentContextImpl.createClassLoader(DeploymentContextImpl.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentContextImpl.createDeploymentClassLoader(DeploymentContextImpl.java:229)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:365)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:406)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.load(InstallerThread.java:211)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.run(InstallerThread.java:100)

Severe:   Application deployment failed: Exception while deploying the app [__admingui]
Info:   Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.10.4 2014-08-08 15:09:00...
Info:   Listening to REST requests at context: /management/domain.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I went about it:

The problem seems to have been the NetBeans GlassFish installer.

1. I downloaded the zip set-up from [GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1
   Download](https://glassfish.java.net/download.html) [>>> **Download : Java EE 7 Full Platform**](http://download.java.net/glassfish/4.1.1/release/glassfish-4.1.1.zip)
2. Unzip to a folder on your disk
3. Set up the Environment variables
   `(SET-UP-DIRECTORY\glassfish4\bin)`
4. From your browser, go to http://localhost:4848
5. On the left tab go to the **Update Tool**
6. Select glassfish-osgi-gui from the list of available add-ons.
7. Click Install and accept the license.
8. Restart the GlassFish server.
9. Open the Admin Console again and click server (Admin Server) in the left navigation column.
10. Click the OSGi Console tab to view a list of the deployed OSGi bundles.

**Note**. You might be prompted to enter the username and password to view the list of OSGi bundles. Confirm that the authorization dialog is not hidden if you do not see a list of bundles in the OSGi Console tab. The default username for the GlassFish 4 server is admin if you installed the server when you installed the IDE. The password is empty by default.